# Trigger a redirect to a page on form submission after three incorrect attempts in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with a coupon field, the page should allow three incorrect attempts after which it has to redirect to another page. I tried setting counters but couldn't make it work. Please help on the below code.

```
function validateCoupon() {

  var couponkey = ["ABCDEF1", "ABCDEF2", "ABCDEF3", "ABCDEF4", "ABCDEF5", "ABCDEF6", "ABCDEF7"];

  var keyinput = $('#COUPON').val().trim().toUpperCase();


  if (couponkey.indexOf(keyinput) > -1) {

    return true;
  } 
else {
    alert("Invalid Key");
    return false;
  }
}
```

After three failed attempts, I want to redirect to another page.

Comment: what did you try with counters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible you kept the counter inside of the function? That might've reset it each time you called the function. You could keep the counter outside the scope of the function.

Try this out.

```
let timesAttemped = 0;

function validateCoupon() {

  var couponkey = ["ABCDEF1", "ABCDEF2", "ABCDEF3", "ABCDEF4", "ABCDEF5", "ABCDEF6", "ABCDEF7"];

  var keyinput = $('#COUPON').val().trim().toUpperCase();


  if (couponkey.indexOf(keyinput) > -1) {

    return true;
  } 
  else if (timesAttempted < 3) {
    alert("Invalid Key");
    timesAttempted++
    return false;
  } else if (timesAttempted === 3) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.lolrofl.com" // any redirect logic here
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using eclipse for JSP, JSTL and javascript for page validation, the 'let' was not recognised. Earlier I had the counter set to 3 and decremented, I tried your way...'timesAttemped' had to be set to 1 initially, since 3rd attempt shud alert and then redirect. In the 2nd else if statement, I had to return false (not sure why) if not it was going to thank you page with no data displayed there. Thank you so much for your help! upvoted!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this without polluting global scope with closure:

```
function couponValidator() {
  var couponkey = ["ABCDEF1", "ABCDEF2", "ABCDEF3", "ABCDEF4", "ABCDEF5", "ABCDEF6", "ABCDEF7"];
  var attempts = 3;

  return function () {
    var keyinput = $('#COUPON').val().trim().toUpperCase();

    if (couponkey.indexOf(keyinput) > -1) {
      return true;
    } 
    else if (--attempts <= 0) {
      window.location.href = "your_url"
    } else {
      alert("Invalid Key");
      return false;
    }
  }  
}

var validate = couponValidator();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I initially tried with decrement but not (--attempts <= 0). I will try this and check. Thanks for your help!